# magento keep showing reindexing required message even after full reindexing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 Community Edition , in my catalog I have 28000 products.

I do reindexing from shell using following command

```
 php indexer.php  --reindexall
```

It shows all indexes have been reindexed.but with in moment if I check

`php indexer.php --status`

It shows all indexes require reindexing even after full reindexing has been done.

How to fix this reindexing problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it once from magento backend also.It might solve your problem.

Comment: @Ashely from magento admin I am not able to reindex, as it takes to much time.

Comment: I already mentioned in my question.I did reindexing  via ssh.Once it is completed again it show all indexes require reindexing.

Answer (score 0):

- 1) I'm having the same issue - in the backend it constantly states that one or more of the indexes are not up to date. Magento 1.7.02
- 2) If I reindex from the back end, everything is reported as good, but the message remains
- 3) If I use ssh - indexer.php --status shows all pending.
- 4) If I then reindex individually, I get the message that each index was rebuilt successfully.
  5 Back in admin it says that one or more of my indexes is out of date!

So, I'm not in a position to answer why its happening, but can I make a suggestion?

If it takes too much time to index from the backend, this might suggest that your database is too big. Have you cleaned up the log tables, etc in the database?

Have you tried ssh reindexing individually? --reindexall can take too much memory/slow your site down. Reindexing individually can also highlight which index has problems.

Cheers,

Comment: Even After individual reindexing I keep getting message to reindex.

Comment: Seems its not a database issue then, since you're not getting time outs or errors. Sorry I can't think what else you can try!

Answer (score 0):

Had exact problem. After many attemps, my solution was to "Optimize" all tables via PHPMyAdmin (guessing that this problem was caused due to large innodb tables).